# How to select values around .(dot) using sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I am running below query in Teradata :

```
sel requesttext from dbc.tables
where tablename='old_employee_table'
```

Result:

```
alter table  DB_NAME.employee_table,no fallback ;
```

I want to get below result using SQL:

```
DB_NAME.employee_table
```

Requesttext can be: 
create set table DB_NAME.employee_table;

DB Name and table can occur anywhere in the result. Since .(dot) is joining them that's why i want to split with .(dot).

Basically I need sql which can result me surrounding values of .(dot)
I want DBName and Tablename in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Teradata person, but this should work for both strings given so far, as long as teradata's `regexp_substr()` supports positive look-behind and positive look-ahead assertions (I might have the Teradata syntax wrong, so a little tweaking may be needed):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(requesttext, '(?<= )(\w+\.\w+)(?=[,$]?)', 1, 1) 
FROM dbc.tables
WHERE tablename='old_employee_table'
```

See the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fM7eC0/1) example. Hopefully it translates to Teradata easily.

The regex looks for and returns the words either side of and including the period, when preceded by a space, and followed by an optional comma or the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with either `regexp_substr()` or `strtok()`.

As Jamie Zawinski said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

So I would go with the `strtok()` method. Also I'm lazy and regular expressions are hard.

Function `strtok()` takes three arguments:

1. The string being split
2. The delimiter to split the string
3. The number of the token to grab.

To get at the `<database>.<table>` from that string that is returned in your query, we can split by a space, grab the third token, then split that by a comma and grab the first token.

That would look like:

```
SELECT strtok(strtok(requestText,' ',3),',',1) 
FROM dbc.tables
WHERE tablename='old_employee_table'
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill.
Your answer working in this case but not in all cases. I want to split the result with . (dot) and get adjacent previous and next result.

Example:
Requesttext: create set table DB_NAME.tablename

Above query not working in this case.

Comment: @Mahesh That should have been in your original specs then.  Please edit your original post and add that and any other string format that may need to be parsed.